# How to calculate average values of an array for each class?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to calculate the average values for each class.

For example:

```py
scores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
classes = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Expected output is

```py
output = [[0, 1.5],
          [1, 4.0]]
```

where output is [[class_indx, avg_value], ...]

I can achieve it using the dictionary. But it means I need to convert the array (list in this example) into dict first and then convert back to array when the job is done. It seems like a workaround in this case and I would prefer to operate directly on arrays.

I guess someone has invented the wheel but just I haven't dug it out from my search. Are there any approaches to do that efficiently?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean `output = [[0: 1.5],...` right?

Comment: It seems you tried something but you didn't post your code, could you show it to us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `itertools.groupby` function:

```
from itertools import groupby

scores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
classes = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

res = []
for k, g in groupby(zip(scores, classes), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    group = list(g)
    res.append([k, sum(i[0] for i in group) / len(group)])

print(res)   # [[0, 1.5], [1, 4.0]]
```

Or with `collections.defauldict` object:

```
from collections import defauldict

scores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
classes = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

d = defaultdict(list)
res = []
for sc, cl in zip(scores, classes):
    d[cl].append(sc)
res = [[cl, sum(lst)/len(lst)] for cl, lst in d.items()]

print(res)   # [[0, 1.5], [1, 4.0]]
```